# can't pass an array from angularjs service to web api

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

Problem is `brandSelection` value doesn't pass in the web api controller>>>

here is my `$http.get()` call from Angular Service:

```
   var _getItemByCategoryId = function (categoryId, currentPageNum, brandSelection) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("Item/GetItemByCategoryId/categoryId/" + categoryId + "/currentPageNum/" + currentPageNum, { params: brandSelection }).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);

        return deferred.promise;

};
```

Here is the WEBAPI  code :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Item/GetItemByCategoryId/categoryId/{categoryId}/currentPageNum/{currentPageNum}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItemByCategoryId(string categoryId, int currentPageNum, string[] brandSelection)
    {
        var item = _itemService.GetItemByCategoryId(categoryId, currentPageNum);
        return Ok(item);
    }
```

The problem is that I get the value of `categoryId` and `currentPageNum` in this Web api controller but `brandSelection` value is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[Formuri]`.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Item/GetItemByCategoryId/categoryId/{categoryId}/currentPageNum/{currentPageNum}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItemByCategoryId(string categoryId, int currentPageNum, [FromUri] string[] brandSelection)
{
    var item = _itemService.GetItemByCategoryId(categoryId, currentPageNum);
    return Ok(item);
}
```